# How to execute oraenv script using java program?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, shell, unix

How to execute oraenv script using java program? How i execute from the Linux Terminal.

```
 [oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 tmp]$ . oraenv
 ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? deltaasm
 The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
 [oracle@DeltaLinOraASM2 tmp]$
```

My oraenv script file contains the following:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=deltaasm
```

How to execute oraenv file using java program.

It is asking ORACLE_SID= ? after executing the script. But from the program it is not getting executed.

```
public class App2 {

public static String RunLinuxGrepCommand(String command) {
    String line = null;
    String strstatus = "";
    try {

        String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", command };
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            strstatus = line;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        pw.flush();
        String stackTrace = sw.toString();
        int lenoferrorstr = stackTrace.length();
        if (lenoferrorstr > 500) {
            strstatus = "Error:" + stackTrace.substring(0, 500);
        } else {
            strstatus = "Error:" + stackTrace.substring(0, lenoferrorstr - 1);

        }
    }
    System.out.println("strstatus" + strstatus);
    return strstatus;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String str = ". oraenv ; deltaasm ";
    App2.RunLinuxGrepCommand(str);

}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand what happens when you use `exec` in Java:

1. A new external processes is created.
2. The process executes the command that you gave
3. The process exits.

So for example if you do this:

```
  exec(". oraenv");
  exec("someOracleCommand");
```

what would happen is:

1. First processes is created.
2. First process executes the ". oraenv" setting environment variables *for that process*.
3. First process exits.
4. Second processes is created.
5. Second process executes "someOracleCommand" with the default environment.
6. Second process exits.

See the problem?  The environment variable settings don't get passed from the first process to the second one.

<sup>Actually, what I said above is untrue.  Running ". oraenv" like that won't work under any circumstances.  The "." command is a shell builtin and is not available unless you are running a shell.  Which the above isn't doing.  The `exec(". orenv")` will fail.</sup>

Solution: You need to run the `. oraenv` and the command in the same shell, something like this:

```
  exec("/bin/bash", "-c",
       ". oraenv ; someOracleCommand");
```

What we have done is put the sequence of shell commands into a single line, and passed that to a shell to execute.  The shell understands how to parse the command sequence ... and will set the environment variables in the shell's environment so that they are available to the following commands running in the shell.

Comment: If you don't want to be prompted, don't forget to set 'ORACLE_SID' and 'ORAENV_ASK=NO' before executing '. oraenv'.

Comment: Good point.  I'm not familiar with what the `oraenv` script is actually doing.  (Another alternative would be to modify your `oraenv` script to include those settings.)

Comment: Hi Stephen C, Thank You for your help.

Comment: i tred this way as you guided but it is failing to set ORACLE_SID

Comment: Either include the relevant shell commands (see Mark's comment) in the command line that you exec, or edit them into the `oraenv` script.